# Only Kinect Wall

Tags: history, video-games, connect-wall

The 4 groups of a total of 16 words can be sorted into four connected groups of 4. The goal is to find the connections of the groups.

[image: Kinect Wall]

Text version:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FOUR | DEMON | CAKE | BRICK |
| EMPIRES | TRAFFIC | WARTHOG | GHOST |
| WORLD | INVADE | DANCE | BARREL |
| MORTAL | GUITAR | TENNIS | GOLD |

Comment: Did you spell connect wrong for a reason?

Comment: Considering it's spelled correctly in the question itself, he probably did it on purpose.

Comment: @Jason_ Yes.  The [Kinect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect) is a peripheral for Xbox 360 and Xbox One.  While the video-games tag is present, not everyone notices those, so the title is meant to further clue people into this connect wall being video-game related.

Comment: Just preliminary thoughts - Warthog has to do with Halo, cake with portal, tennis maybe with wii, guitar with guitar hero (maybe those last two deal with special peripherals required to play? supported by dance and the dance dance revolution pad). Mortal might be Mortal Kombat but I'm not sure, maybe goes with ghost and demon.
_
More thoughts: World and empires and invade maybe has to do with Sid Mier's civ or age of empires, possibly ties in with 4th installment__Even more: 4 might refer to #possible players

Comment: Note that it’s considered anti-social to post text as images without also posting it as text.  Blind people can use the Internet, but (apparently) software that can extract characters from pixels isn’t widely available. (Look at some of the other Only Connect puzzles for examples.)

Comment: @PeregrineRook check out http://ai.stackexchange.com/ you might be surprised. But your point still stands haha

Comment: @PeregrineRook good point.  Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @TMpearce example

> Grouping by decade

Group 1

> TENNIS (Pong- 1972)
>  BRICK (Breakout - 1976)
>  EMPIRE(Classic Empire-1977)
>  INVADE (Space Invaders - 1978)

Group 2

> GHOST (Pac-Man - 1980)
>  BARREL (Donkey Kong - 1981)
>  TRAFFIC (Frogger - 1981)
>  FOUR (Tetris - 1984)

Group 3

> MORTAL (Mortal Kombat - 1992)
>  DEMON (Doom - 1993)
>  GOLD (Goldeneye - 1997)
>  DANCE (DDR-1998)

Group 4

> WARTHOG (Halo -2001)
>  WORLD (World of Warcraft - 2004)
>  GUITAR (Guitar Hero -2005)
>  CAKE (Portal -2007)

Original 11/14 correct

> Removed EMPIRE, was wrong based on a comment, Also know that TRAFFIC is (Frogger - 1981), there are two others wrong - almost surely FOUR and TENNIS
>  Mario games: TENNIS (Mario Tennis - 2000) , BARREL (Donkey Kong - 1981), TRAFFIC (Mario Kart - 1992), FOUR (Mario Party - 1998)
>  Sci-Fi games: DEMON (Doom - 1993), INVADE (Space Invaders - 1978), WARTHOG (Halo -2001), CAKE (Portal -2007)
> BRICK (Breakout - 1976), GUITAR (Guitar Hero -2005),  GHOST (Pac-Man - 1980),  DANCE (DDR-1998), MORTAL (Mortal Kombat - 1992), GOLD (Goldeneye - 1997)

Comment: 11 correct game titles.  Incorrect groupings, but I like where you are going with it.

Comment: Correct groups and correct games aside from one, but I'll edit that in for you.

Answer (score 3):

Updated:

> Taking the `history` tag into account, I thought the games might be organized by decade of release.

1st:

> **1970s**
> BRICK: breakout(1976)
> INVADE: space invaders(1978)

2nd:

> **1980s**
> GHOST: pac-man(1980)
> BARREL: donkey kong(1981)
> TRAFFIC: frogger (1981)

3rd:

> **1990s**
> DEMON: doom (1993)
> EMPIRES: age of empires (1997)
> MORTAL: mortal kombat(1992)
> DANCE: ddr (1998)

4th:

> **2000s**
> CAKE: portal(2007)
> WARTHOG: halo(2001)
> GUITAR: guitar hero (2005)
> WORLD: world of warcraft (2004)

**Unknown**

> FOUR: ??? (19__)
> TENNIS: ??? (19__)
> GOLD: ??? (19__)

Original:
Here's a try, with some certain to be wrong:

One group:

> *Objectives*: **Cake** (Portal), **Gold** (many many games), **Brick** (Breakout), **Four** in a row (Connect Four)

Second group:

> *Things to be avoided*: **Ghost** (Pacman), **Barrel** (Donkey Kong), **Traffic** (Frogger), **Demon** (???)

Third group:

> *Games with two-player competition mode*: **Dance** Dance Revolution/**Guitar** Hero/**Tennis** (Wii sports)/**Mortal** Kombat

Fourth group:

> *Key word is last in a multi-word title*:DCS: A-10C **Warthog**/Age of **Empires**/Super Mario **World**/Space **Invaders**

Comment: Demon could be from Doom.

Comment: You've correctly mapped 8 of the games to the word on the grid.  None of the groups are correct.

Comment: So, I was bad at counting.  9 of these game titles are correct.

Comment: Note: the 9/16 correct count is for the original guess I posted (now at the bottom of the updated post)

Comment: EMPIRES is not for Age of Empires, but the other games are correct.  Also, good job on noticing the history tag.

Comment: EMPIRES could be (classic) Empire (1997), or Civilization(1991)...?

Answer (score 2):

I'll give this a try, since nobody else has.

> Brick (Breakout)
>  Ghost (Pacman)
>  Invade (Space Invaders)
>  Barrel (Donkey Kong)
>
>  Which are all classic arcade games.

Another could be

> Dance (Dance Dance Revolution)
>  Guitar (Guitar Hero)
>  Tennis (Wii Sports)
>  Gold (Kinect Sports)
>
>  Which all uses a special peripheral (based on a suggestion by Avik Mohan)
>  I'm fairly unsure about the Gold one. I guessed the last one might use the Kinect, since it was in the title, and this was the closest one.

Comment: 6 of the 8 game titles are correct, but neither group is correct.

Comment: Does that mean the words each reference a different video game?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @DavidStarkey When you say neither group is correct, do you mean that the groups' headings (arcade games and games with peripherals) are incorrect, or that some of the games within the groups are incorrect?

Comment: @DooplissForce both.

Answer (score 2):

Partial (just a list of games in the grid)

> | FOUR ?  | DEMON doom  | CAKE  portal  | BRICK breakout |
>  | EMPIRES ? | TRAFFIC ? | WARTHOG ? | GHOST pac-man   |
>  | WORLD ?  | INVADE  s. invaders | DANCE DDR  | BARREL Donkey Kong |
>  | MORTAL Kombat | GUITAR g. hero | TENNIS ?  | GOLD  ?  |

That's 6/8 for the Kruga's list and 8/16 from tmpearce as per hints

I also guess that:

> <s>TRAFFIC is a reference to GTA</s> disproved

And that:

> FOUR, GOLD, EMPIRES and WORLD can almost be in their on category called "postfixes added to too many games to count" ;)

Comment: I believe adding 2 spaces to the end of a line and continuing on the next line will continue the block (quote/spoiler).  You could also click edit on [Kruga's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41694/2071) and see how they did it.

Comment: Also, most of the game titles are correct so far.  TRAFFIC, however, is not.

Comment: Thank you, that (adding 2 spaces to the end of the line) worked.

Comment: @DavidStarkey just commented on my answer that 9/16 there are correct FYI

Comment: Well, unless it was DOOM, like Peter Taylor said (already on the list) I don't really see another game I'm sure about including...